# Sending a form with "FormData()" in javascript, does not display html response correctly. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a form using two different method.

But browser does not display html content that return from server in method 2.

The form:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/return_form/sayform" ><input name="refid"  value="33862136">
```

---

Method 1:(Form, Submit)

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.form1.submit()">POST Data</button>
```

Result 1:

The browser POST the form to server and server response an HTML content and browser display HTML content according to server response.

---

Method 2:(JavaScript function, using "FormData" and "XMLHttpRequest")

`

```
function Send() {
   var data = new FormData();
   data.append("refid", "33862136");
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/return_form/sayform", false);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         //do some thing
      }
   };
   xhr.send(data);
};`


<button type="button" onclick="Send()">POST Data</button>
```

Result 2:

The brwoser POST the form with the header of

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryOdbZ7kv4ZlCRmEkk
```

and request payload of

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryOdbZ7kv4ZlCRmEkk    
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="refid"
33862136
------WebKitFormBoundaryOdbZ7kv4ZlCRmEkk--
```

and server response HTML content (exactly like method 1 server response) but the browser does not display the HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of Ajax is that the response is handled by the JavaScript you write and not by automatically displaying it as a new page.

If you want to do something with the result, then you need to write code to do that: In the place where you have written `//do some thing`.

If you do want to display it as a new page: Don't use Ajax.